# Can macro expansion contain (declare ...) expressions?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

The Common Lisp Hyperspec states "Macro forms cannot expand into declarations; declare expressions must appear as actual subexpressions of the form to which they refer."

I'm confused on the meaning of "expand into". A macro such as the following won't work for obvious reasons:

```
(defmacro optimize-fully ()
    `(declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0))))
```

But what if the macro expansion merely *contains* a `(declare ...)` expression?

```
(defmacro defun-optimized (name (&rest lambda-list) &rest body)
    `(defun ,name ,lambda-list
        (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))
        ,@body))

(defun-optimized foobar (a b)
    (* a b))
```

Is this a violation of the spec? The CL implementation I use, SBCL, does not complain, and in fact, the macro above seems to work precisely as expected. What gives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your first example is exactly what it's prohibiting. You couldn't have code like that combined with something like this:

```
(defun optimized (a b)
  (optimize-fully)
  (+ a b))
```

I sometimes see code like this, though:

```
(defvar *optimization-settings* '(optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))

(defun foo (a b)
  (declare #.*optimization-settings*)
  ...)
```

Comment: So when the spec prohibits macro calls from "expand[ing] into declarations", it's only talking about _immediate_ (I can't think of a better word) expansions?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: And the author of the book "Let Over Lambda" suggests defining reader macros that expand to declare forms, since reader macros get expanded before normal macros are expanded.