# Why can't constants be used as array dimensions in Common Lisp type specifiers?

Tags: arrays, common-lisp, sbcl

At least some implementations of Common Lisp don't allow user-defined constants to be used as array dimensions in some type specifiers.  For example, in SBCL, this code:

```
(defconstant +len+ 3)

(defun foo (x) 
  (declare (type (simple-array fixnum (+len+)) x))
  x)
```

generates this error:

```
; in: DEFUN FOO
;     (TYPE (SIMPLE-ARRAY FIXNUM (+LEN+)) X)
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   bad dimension in array type: +LEN+
```

Why? It seems surprising that user-defined constants can't be used in type specifiers, since it would be desirable to be able to coordinate multiple type specifiers using some kind of global definition.  I understand that type specifiers need to be completely understandable at compile-time.  But I would have thought that a compiler would be able to replace symbols defined with `defconstant` by their literal values.  I would have thought that this was one of the purposes of `defconstant`.  (I've been unsuccessful, so far, in getting deeper understanding of this issue from the Common Lisp Hyperspec, CLTL2, the SBCL manual, or what Google has turned up.  I suspect the answer is there in some form ....)

Comment: Are you saying (implying) that there are some LISP compilers that allow this, but others that do no?

Comment: I don't want to make claims about compilers or uses of type specifications that I haven't tested. I don't know what might happen in different cases. However, I've found that in CCL, for example, in `(map '(simple-array fixnum (4)) #'1+ (the (simple-array fixnum (4)) arr))`, replacing the first 4 with a constant generates an error, but replacing the second 4 only generates a warning, and the correct result is returned.  In SBCL, by contrast, both replacements cause errors.

Comment: @Mars When you say "replacing the first `4` with a constant generates an error", it sounds like you mean you've replaced `4` with the _name_ of a constant, which is quite different from replacing `4` with the _value_ of a constant. `defconstant`s aren't like C `#define`s which do textual substitution.

Comment: Yes, @JoshuaTaylor, right--I did mean substituting the string "+len+" for the string "4" in the source file or in what I typed in at the repl prompt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I imagine that something like this would work:

```
(defconstant +len+ 3)

(deftype len-3-fixnum-array () `(array fixnum (,+len+)))

(defun foo (x)
  (declare (type len-3-fixnum-array x))
  (print x))

(foo (make-array 3 :element-type 'fixnum))
;; #(0 0 0)

(foo (make-array 4 :element-type 'fixnum))
;; The value #(0 0 0 0) is not of type (VECTOR FIXNUM 3).
;;    [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

However, you need to keep in mind that type annotations are only recommendations, compilers are allowed to ignore them altogether.

---

I.e. the problem isn't that you can't use constants in the `declare` form, it's that it acts as if it was quoted, so your constant there doesn't evaluate to 3, it just stays the symbol `+len+`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the actual problem:  the list `(+len+)` whose element is a symbol isn't a valid dimension specifier, but the list produced by `(list +len+)`, whose element is the value of `+len+`, is.

Comment: Thanks--nice trick wvxvw.  Thanks for that extra comment @JoshuaTaylor, highlighting the significance of the `backquote`/`comma` in wvxvw's answer.

Comment: wvxvw's method doesn't require that the length parameter be a constant, it appears.  Also embedding the backquoted declaration directly into the `defun` seems to work as well: `(defun foo (x) `(declare (type (simple-array fixnum (,+len+)) x)) (print x))`.  This seems to be exactly the solution I wanted.

Comment: Accepting wvxvw's answer despite the fact that the other and answers provided important information.  wvxvw's answer gives a clean solution to the underlying problem, and I can only accept one.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo and an error two comments back.  Should have been `(defun foo (x) \`(declare (type (simple-array fixnum (,+len+)) x)) (print x))`, and it doesn't work.  Compiles, but doesn't provide type checking, etc.  Just gets ignored.

Comment: @Mars declarations have this peculiar "inconvenient" property. You cannot "glue" them from pieces by using macros either (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645299 ). But similar to the the code in the answer there, you could use a reader-macro (although that would be probably a little weird).

Comment: @Mars: You can use the read time evaluation reader macro (`#.`) with your declaration, i.e. `(defun foo (x) #.\`(declare (type (simple-array fixnum (,+len+)) x)) (print x))`. That should solve your problem because now the expansion will happen at read time instead of macro-expansion time.

Comment: Ah, excellent @Rörd, wvxvw.  Pushing the reader macro operator inside, as in `(defun foo (x) (declare (type (simple-array fixnum (#.+len+)) x)) (print x))`, seems to work as well.  This seems like the cleanest solution for what I wanted.  I should learn a bit more about reader macros--didn't know about this.

Comment: @Mars: BTW, you might want to wrap your `defconstant` in `eval-when` to make sure the constant will always be defined at read time, e.g. `(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute) (defconstant +len+ 3))`.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with a 2D array:

```
(defconstant board-width  4)
(defconstant board-height 3)

(setq *board* (make-array '(board-width board-height) :initial-element 0))
```

I always got the error

```
The value BOARD-WITH is not of type SB-INT:INDEX.
```

So I changed the last line this way:

```
(setq *board* (make-array (list board-width board-height) :initial-element 0))
```

and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the ANSI CL spec, the syntax for types is clearly defined. For [simple-array](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_smp_ar.htm#simple-array):

```
simple-array [{element-type | *} [dimension-spec]]

dimension-spec::= rank | * | ({dimension | *}*)
```

Where:

```
dimension---a valid array dimension.

element-type---a type specifier.

rank---a non-negative fixnum.
```

The `valid array dimension` is then explained as a fixnum.

There are no variables or constant identifiers in an `simple-array` type declaration. Type declarations have their own syntax and are not evaluated or similar. They are type expressions which can appear in code in special places (-> declarations).

**You can use `DEFTYPE` to create new type names and use those, though.**

Comment: I hard read that part of the spec, but I wasn't sure whether a variable defined to a particular fixnum value using `defconstant` counted as a fixnum for the purposes of defining array dimensions.  Your comment clarifies that for me.

Answer (score 4):

Well, because nobody seems to actually give what the questioner needs, here it is:

```
(defun foo (x) 
  (declare (type (simple-array fixnum (#.+len+)) x))
  x)
```

`#.` is a standard readmacro that evaluates the value in the read-time. Lisp form only sees what was expanded. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhf.htm

Answer (score 3):

The other two answers tell you [how to work around the limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19088149/850781) and [where the limitation is specified in the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19088152/850781).

I will try to tell you **where this limitation is coming from**.

The reason is that the Lisp declarations are intended not just as code documentation for the *human* reader, but also as a help for the *compiler* in optimizing the code. I.e., the array size, when declared, should permit the compiler to allocate a fixed size array, if necessary, and infer the storage requirements for array indexes. It is similar to the `C` limitation which forbids code like

```
int N = 10;
int v[N];
```

When you start looking at the declarations from the compiler's POV, the requirements will become quite natural.

Comment: Thanks sds.  That's what I was wondering.  But having to put literals in array type specifiers is bug-prone, makes code harder to maintain, etc.  So I figured there would be a good reason to allow C-ish macros, and `defconstant` seemed like the only language element that might do that.  However, it turns out that C-style macros aren't needed;  Regular Lisp macros are enough, as @wvxvw's answer showed.